# Which things would you check when you monitoring a server

Tags: linux, monitoring

I am using Sensu to monitore few server and I have installed some basic scripts to check if everything is ok.
For the moment I have : Apache Alive, SQL alive, SQL replication link,Back Up verification  RAM, CPU and disk usage.

What other things fail/don't run as expected on a web server and what are the most common failure ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have the key area's covered. I would typically monitor the following on a web server:

Apache processes, 
Web site HTTP responses, 
SQL Database status, maybe transaction count, wait times etc..., 
SQL Replication status, 
Backup process status, 
RAM utlisation, 
Disk Space free %, 
CPU Load

If you can, monitoring log files for known error messages is also common, but your templates in Sensu might already do that for certain applications.